# Old SQL database- trying to store string with text with spaces

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm working on an old mySql database, trying to insert new rows.  The code is below (I know it's ugly- just trying to get it to work before making it work well!).

Everything seems to work unless the $newbuilding variable includes a space.  That variable will always be a string, but if that string includes a space (for example, "Building 01"), anything after the space is omitted when it's inserted into the table.  Works fine if there are no spaces.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks for any feedback!

```
$SQLstmt = "insert into homes_mail_lists set " .
           "`tbl_id` = ${tbl_main["tbl_id"]}, " .
           "`item_id` = ${Iitem_id}, " .
           "`building` = '${newbuilding}', " .
           "`updt_user` = '${cp_valid_user}', " .
           "`updt_dttm` = null";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out my problem- sorry for wasting anyone's time! If you're curious or run into a similar problem- my issue wasn't with the SQL, it was with the html provided to the $newbuilding variable (it was not enclosed in quotes, so wasn't recognizing two words as one string).